# Substitute word "open" with various conditions

Tags: text-processing, sed

I write a script of `sed` substitution with these condition:

- If the word "open" precedes another word, change the word "open" to "x".
- If the word "open" does not precedes another word, change the word "open" to "l".

For example expected input:

```
open
open door
open blue door
can you open door
the door is open
```

And the expected output would be:

```
l
x door
x blue door
can you x door
the door is l
```

The code that I just achieved is only (because I'm really new on it):

```
sed 's/open/x/g'
```

Comment: Please give a precise example of input, expected output, and observed output. Having said that, it's probably just that `.*` is matching the rest of the line, and you are expecting it to match… a single word? I'm not even sure.

Comment: I write a script of sed substitution with this condition:
_If the input is two words, then i should change the first word into 'X'_.

For example, I input:
`open door`
Then with sed substitution, it becomes:
`x door`

Comment: Here i have edited my question. And sadly, I am looking for the sed solution (not even gsed).

Comment: In your example, it looks as if you want to replace the word "door" with "x" unconditionally, is this correct? I don't see how "replacing _two_ words" relates to this example.

Comment: Actually the condition is _if there are a word after open_. It seems confusing sorry, i will edit the title again.

Comment: still unclear. What should happen to the line `open`? Replaced by `x` or stay `open`?

Comment: It would be another letter actually in my case, but i think i will figure it out alone later. But if you ask, it will be turned into letter 'l'.

Comment: okay, so it's `open door` => `x door`, `there is an open door` => `there is an x door`, `open` => `l` and likely `the door is open` => `the door is l` … all correct?

Comment: Yeah it's! Sorry for the confusing question ..

Comment: but the `open` in the first line should be changed to `l`, too, right?

Comment: Yeah sorry my mistake

Comment: Are you done changing the expected output? You invalidate every given answer with each edit.

Comment: I think it is enough thanks to @wolf-revo-cats that help me to validate them. Sorry for this confusing things around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We still can only guess how to handle punctuation, so cases like `open, close` where there are two words but they are semantically separated … are **not** included (no replacement takes place!).

So far, for me the following works:

```
$ cat test.txt
open  
open door
open blue door
can you open door
the door is open
$ sed -E 's/\<open([[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]+)/x\1/g;s/\<open[[:space:]]*$/l/g' test.txt
l
x door
x blue door
can you x door
the door is l
```

Comment: upvote. We could add `[[:punct:]]*` for punctuation, and I'd use `[^[:space:]]` instead of alnum.

Answer (score 2):

Using the example data that you provide in the question:

```
$ sed -E -e 's/\<open([[:space:]]+)\</x\1/g' -e 's/\<open\>/l/g' file
l
x door
x blue door
can you x door
the door is l
```

This applies two `sed` substitutions to each line.  The first substitution matches the word `open` followed any number of spaces or tabs and a start-of-word pattern (`\<`).  It replaces this with `x` and however many spaces or tabs were found. This replaces `open` if it precedes a word.

The second substitution replaces any remaining word `open` with `l`.

Comment: Nice use of word boundaries!